# How to write multiple sed commands in a file?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to delete blank lines from a file using the sed command `/^$d` then I want to add a line to the end of the file. So when I try doing this in my command file

```
/^$/d \
$ a \
My color is blue
```

then executing I get and errors that says: extra characters after command on the first line. I've read you use '\' when ending a line command why is it reading it as extra character???

Comment: Don't continue '\' the first line.

Comment: `\ ` is only use as new line separator in pattern (`s///`, `//,//`) or append,insert (`a \ `, `i \ ` [without trailing space]) and their following litteral lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is the continuation <kbd>\</kbd> character on the end of the first line.

You need it on the second line (for the `a` command) to give the `a` command something to append but the first command is complete by the time the end-of-line is seen. By continuing the line you are confusing `sed` as it thinks the commands run together.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Etan Reisner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28846276/45375) helpful answer:

- It's *always* OK to place *complete* `sed` commands on separate lines.
- Conversely, if a line break is *part* of a *single* command (such as the `a` function call in this case), you must `\`-escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution if you like to try:

```
awk 'NF; END {print "new line"}' file
```

`NF` is only true if there are some fields on the line, ie have data.
`END {print "new line"}` This adds a line at the end of the file.